# remove slash from JSON

Tags: json, scala, serialization

Here I am using `write()` method of JSON serialization  for converting a case class to a JSON object .
for example - 
case class `Data("data":String)` and I want to convert this into json then it can be done by

```
val json = net.liftweb.json.serialization.write(Data("here is something"))
```

then it converts it in to  `{"data":"here is something"}`

But if I want to convert it also into another json object for example -

```
case class Result("message":String , Information : String)

val result =  net.liftweb.json.serialization.write(Result("success",json))
```

then result shows like -

```
{"message":"success" , "Information":{"{"\data\":"\here is something\"}"}}
```

But I don't want slash here in result . so what is best scenario to remove this  .

one approach which i can do here is use result.replace("\","") .
But I am using a lot of route here so This is not best scenario  for me to change it everywhere so for remove the slash everywhere what should be best approach

Comment: well... that is just how strings are in Scala/Java. Any double quotes inside a String need to be `escaped` with a `\`. It is actually just `{"data":"here is something"}` and `\` is there just for you to be able to understand.

Comment: I think in reality what you wanted was this: `val result =  net.liftweb.json.serialization.write(Result("success", Data("data"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `case class Result("message":String , Information : Data)`.